# animation on hiding/unhiding a view

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to hide/show a view on button tap.Currently i am doing

> view.hidden=YES;

and

> view.hidden=NO;

But i am looking for some animation while hiding and showing the view.
Suggestion please.

Comment: what kind of animation do you want to do?  fade in / face out?  slide the view into place?  or something more complicated?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902316/flip-view-animation-not-working?rq=1 and see if it helps

Comment: @MichaelDautermann i am not sure,i m looking for something different than flipping,fadein etc.

Comment: It's better to have a practical, answerable question; right now this reads "give me ideas on designing my animation" which isn't something that strikes me as being answerable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this animation that will show and hide your view over 2 seconds

```
                //your view displayed
                view.alpha = 1.0

                //animate you view hidden
                [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     view.alpha = 0.0;
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    //view completed 
               }];
```

Comment: i got this working well    CATransition *applicationLoadViewIn = [CATransition animation];
[applicationLoadViewIn setDuration:1];
[applicationLoadViewIn setType:kCATransitionReveal];
[applicationLoadViewIn setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn]];
[[myview layer] addAnimation:applicationLoadViewIn forKey:kCATransitionReveal];

Comment: Go deal.  If you continue to dig deeper into CATransition and CAAnimations, you'll see that this is usually the preferred method when creating a very robust animation.  For something like what you are doing though you can usually use UIView animation sequences though and be just fine.

Comment: Glad it it working for you though and you were able to solve you problem!

Answer (score 0):

Give **tag** of Button is **101** and set `view.hidden=NO;`

**write in button method**

```
-(void)btnMetho:(UIButton *)sender
{
  if(sender.tag == 101)
  {
      if(!view.isHidden)
        view.hidden=YES;
     button.tag = 102; 
  }
  else
  {
    if(view.isHidden)
        view.hidden=NO;
     button.tag = 101;
  }

}
```

**EDIT :**

for animation 
set `view.alpha to 0` (***corresponds to hidden = YES)*** or `view.alpha to 1` (***hidden = NO***).

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^() {
    view.alpha = 1 /or/ 0;
}]
```

Comment: @FirstTimer - if my answer is helpful then you can also accept it ..and +1 for u...i glad to help you :) thanks

Comment: You're doing logic based on the tag of the sender, but I'm confused as to how it plays into the solution. I ask because it is not clear how that part works or why it is necessary. It seems to me that maybe that whole method could be replaced by `view.hidden = !view.hidden;` but maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @CarlVeazey- declare UIView and UIButton public (in .h) file and create both in   `-(void)viewDidLoad` and put `self.button.tad=101; //or as you want`..and check my code